# I am getting "Undefined type" in my implementation of cvSnakeImage()

Tags: java, c++, opencv, javacv

I am using JavaCV with OpenCV in eclipse. This allows me to have all access to the C++ functions in OpenCV like cvSnakeImage(). With the code below I am getting:

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method cvSnakeImage(opencv_core.IplImage, Point, int, float, float, float, int, int, int, int) is undefined for the type OpenCv at OpenCv.main(OpenCv.java:17)"

Any Ideas?

```
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;
import java.awt.Point;

public class MyProgram {
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    IplImage image = cvLoadImage("pic.jpg");
        Point pt = new Point(10,8);
        Point pt2 = new Point(30,50);
        float alpha=20/100.0f; 
        float beta=20/100.0f; 
        float gamma=20/100.0f; 


        cvSnakeImage(image,pt,1,alpha,beta,gamma,1,3,8,0 );   

        cvSaveImage("output.jpg", image);
        cvReleaseImage(image);
    System.out.println( "Hello");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what this is saying is that there is no static function that takes these parameters

```
cvSnakeImage(opencv_core.IplImage, Point, int, float, float, float, int, int, int, int)
```

As `cvLoadImage` seems to be working I guess that you have your projects set up correctly.

**Check the parameters for the function `cvSnakeImage`**

According to some docs I found, the third to last parameter `size` should be of type

```
CvSize size; 
size.width=3; 
size.height=3;
```

see this [example](http://download.andol.info/cvsnakeimage.cpp)

Look at the above link that I sent you? It looks like the second to last parameter is a type CvTermCriteria. The forth the last parameter is CV_VALUE whatever that is.

Comment: When I add CvSize like above I get: "width/height cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: I used, " CvSize size = cvSize(3,3);" and that works, but I am still getting the same error on cvSnakeImage

Comment: Glad you could help yourself with the CvSize object.  So if you now using size as a parameter, you are not going to get exactly the same error.  Did you look at the link I sent you?  It looks like the second to last parameter is a type `CvTermCriteria`.  The forth the last parameter is `CV_VALUE` whatever that is.